# Client app send request in same session after Response.Write( ..) on my aspx page. Can i retrieve this data?

Tags: asp.net

There are two web application.

WebApp1 send POST-request(1) to WebApp2. Then WebApp2 send POST-response(2) to WebApp1. I am developing WebApp2. I create simple aspx-page. OnLoad event give me ability to process (1) & (2) and provide app logic. To make response(2) I am using Response.Write(...). But! after response(2) WebApp1 send one more request to my app, to confirm, that my response recieved succesfully. That is the problem. I don't know how to catch (3). Response.Write(...) writes to response stream, but doesn't return any data from WebApp1.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            logger.Trace(" -- POST REQUEST ...");
            string requestBody;
            using (StreamReader writer = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                requestBody = writer.ReadToEnd();
                logger.Trace("Request body:\n{0}", XmlHelper.FormatStringToXml(requestBody));
            }
            string responseBody = ProcessRequest(requestBody);

            logger.Trace("Response body:\n{0}", XmlHelper.FormatStringToXml(responseBody));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
            {
                SendPostXmlResponse(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Error("Cant send empty response. No response was sended.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Error(" -- GET REQUEST is not supported. No actions were made.");
        }
    }


    private void SendPostXmlResponse(string response)
    {          
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream (SmsService.StringToUTF8ByteArray(response)))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
```

Method SendPostXmlResponse(string response) must return data, recieved from client, after response is sended.

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to do it can not work because from the moment you start sending data, you can not stop sending and start reading again.

Its better to send a link to the other side with some code, and the other side replay to with a new call to this link as confirmation that get the data.

At the bottom, if after you send all your data this parametre is `Response.IsClientConnected` is true, then the data are there and the communication is not lost.

Comment: Can i achieve this using HTTP handlers? They provide a way to interact with HTTP requests before they get to a web page.

Comment: @Kabazakra You have a client and a server, and you ask to reverse for the call, the client to be the server, and the server be the client. This is not possible, unless you make a second connection - or just be sure that the connection is not lost.

Comment: Can you give some code example, how to use Response.IsClientConnected to get response (from client) after writing my app response to Response.OutputStream ?

Comment: @Kabazakra I have give you, you just check the IsClientConnected return true, means the the client still is in good connection and read data from you.

Comment: WebApp1 developed by other company. It is hard to change their API. Can i get "Response on response" from WebApp1 using ASP.NET capabilities. Maybe migration from aspx to web-service has sense?